# Como puedo borrar un elemento seleccionado en un combobox de un array

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Tengo que conseguir borrar de un array un elemento que está guardado en un combobox. 
He creado una estructura llamada Registro y he metido los datos en un array mediante textboxes y el perfil se guarda en un combobox.
Ahora necesito que al seleccionar ese perfil en el combobox y apretar un botón se borre tanto el perfil del combobox como los datos del perfil en el array.

```
Public Class Form1

    Structure Registro
        Dim Nombre As String
        Dim Apellidos As String
        Dim Teléfono As Integer
        Dim Dirección As String
    End Structure

    Dim datos(0) As Registro
    Private Sub bt_añadir_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_añadir.Click
        If comprobar_blancos() = 1 Then
            MsgBox("Hay algún campo vacío")
        Else
            cb_perfiles.Items.Add(tb_nombre.Text & " " & tb_apellidos.Text)

            datos(UBound(datos)).Nombre = tb_nombre.Text
            datos(UBound(datos)).Apellidos = tb_apellidos.Text
            datos(UBound(datos)).Teléfono = tb_telefono.Text
            datos(UBound(datos)).Dirección = tb_direccion.Text

            ReDim Preserve datos(UBound(datos) + 1)
        End If
        Limpiar()
        tb_nombre.Focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bt_borrar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt_borrar.Click
        If cb_perfiles.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
            MsgBox("No has seleccionado ningun perfil")
        Else
            Dim datoslist As ArrayList
            datoslist = New ArrayList(datos)
            cb_perfiles.Items.Remove(cb_perfiles.SelectedItem)
            datoslist.RemoveAt(cb_perfiles.SelectedItem)
        End If
        Limpiar()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Este es el código entero pero donde tengo el problema es en bt_borrar_Click.

Comment: Este codigo "pareceria" correcto. A ver, donde es que no esta borrando? en donde se deberia borrar? cual es la estructura de donde queres sacar el item?

Comment: En principio se debería de borrar el item seleccionado en cb_perfiles del array datos y del combobox cb_perfiles pero no se si estaría bien haciendo lo que he hecho yo.(Transformar el array en arraylist y utilizar el removeat)